# Additive real function on finite union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question comes from a text on Lebesgue integration, which I'm using for self-study.  The chapter this comes from is introductory material, mostly set theory, compactness, and functions:

> Suppose a real function $f$ is additive on disjoint sets (i.e. $f(A \cup B)$ = $f(A) + f(B)$ whenever $A \cap B = \emptyset$).  Prove that
>
> $f(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \ldots \cup A_{n})$ = $\sum$ $f(A_{r})$ - $\sum f(A_{rs})$ + $\sum f(A_{rst})$ $\cdots$ + $(-1)^{n-1}f(A_{12 \ldots n})$
>
> where $A_{rs \ldots z} := A_{r} \cap A_{s} \cap \ldots \cap A_{z}$ when the indices $r,s,\ldots,z$ are distinct and summations are over all possible sets of indices.

This seems similar to the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Indeed, if the function $f$ gives the size of each set (in the case where every $A_{i}$ were finite), then this formula simplifies to the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for $n$ sets.

How would one prove this for the general case?

Comment: Look up a proof of the inlcusion-exclusion principle and see if it generalises?

Comment: Hint. Look at a proof of the inclusion-exclusion principle - perhaps an inductive one. Check that the only property of "counting" that it uses is that the number of elements is additive on disjoint unions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked wonders.  I had actually forgotten the induction proof of the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, so that helped quite a bit.